# For syntax of least absolute deviation from package 'L1pack'

Tags: r, regression, error, least-absolute-deviations

I am trying to use the least absolute deviation regression from my dataset which has one column of dependent variable and multiple columns of independent variables. I tried using the following syntax but get errors where the 'co' contains the dataset and the 12th column is my dependent variable:

```
 co_reg1=lad(co[,12]~co[,2]+co[,3]+co[,5]+co[,7]+co[,8]+co
 [,9]+co[,11]+co[,2]*co[,11])
```

but I get error saying:

```
 argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

So I also tried this method:

```
 co_reg1=lad(cbind(co[,2],co[,3],co[,5],co[,7],co[,8],co[,9],co[,11],co[,2]
 *co[,11]),co[,12])
```

But I still get error saying I need the arguments for x and y to be in matrix form.

May I get help on this?

Comment: It works for me `lad(mtcars[,1] ~ mtcars[,2] + mtcars[,3]*mtcars[,4])`... The question is off-topic and you didn't provide a reproducible example what makes it impossible to answer. `lad` takes as argument standard R formula and then parses it using the same methods as functions like `lm`, so it should work if you use it with valid input data and use it correctly.

Comment: Now I get it. When I delete a library something like "ldr" package, it works. I tried to call this ldr package to use summary.lad function. However since it seems like I cannot call both functions, probably summary.lad is not supposed to give the summary result for least absolute deviation regression result. Because in some other package lad function means different one if I am correct. So I think there was some collusion.

Comment: May I know the name of the function? Cuz theoretically people say it is not available.

Comment: You are right. What kind of summary would you need?

Comment: t-test for coefficients and for overall f-test and R square values

Comment: But most of such methods are related to linear regression and assume normality of residuals etc. while in L1 regression they follow Laplace's distribution. The same with R2 - it is related to linear regression.

Comment: So do you mean it is not possible to get these values from lad function?

Comment: No. Moreover, as far as I know, other packages (e.g. quantreg) don't provide them either. If you have some specific tests in mind and can provide literature on using them, you can submit feature request on https://github.com/faosorios/L1pack . But I am not aware of any "standard" tests to conduct with L1 regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone's going to complain that this question belongs to other stackoverflow forum. But the quick take on your question is, you need to follow the standard R idiom. That is, for function like `lad`, it wants a `formula` like `y ~ x1 + ...` and a `data` object. To use your syntax, you want `l1fit` which accepts a `x` and `y`. Just read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. The example I show above is using y~x1+... already but getting error.

Comment: @Eric Try use `l1fit` and see if you get the same error. And read the doc.

Comment: Yes when I supply x and y as required by the syntax it works. But since my ultimate goal is to use the summary.lad function over it, I may need to use lad() function. When I run the lad() function with the working syntax in l1fit, I get error saying "supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'" which I don't understand either.

Comment: Now I get it. When I delete a library something like "ldr" package, it works. I tried to call this ldr package to use summary.lad function. However since it seems like I cannot call both functions, probably summary.lad is not supposed to give the summary result for least absolute deviation regression result. Because in some other package lad function means different one if I am correct. So I think there was some collusion.